# How to comment a file itself in VSCode file explorer?

Tags: comments, visual-studio-code, file-manager

I have some similar files that can confuse so I want to tell them apart right in the file panel - without opening. As I remember there was such a feature but I can't find it. Does anybody know?

[image: Something like that]